# Ошибка при написании sql запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Выдает ошибку:

```
"Ошибочное или пропущенное зарезервированное слово или аргумент в инструкции SELECT или неверная пунктуация."
```

Несколько рз переписывала запрос, но все равно не могу найти и исправить ошибку

```
string Query_Workers = "SELECT Worker.ID_Worker AS ID, Worker.Lastname AS Фамилия, Worker.Firstname AS Имя"

+ "Worker.Fathername AS Отчество, Worker.Birthdate AS[Дата рождения], Worker.Address AS Адрес"

+ "Worker.Tel AS Телефон, Worker.PassData AS[Паспортные данные], Worker.[Date_Employment] AS[Дата приема]"

+ "Worker.[Date_Dismissa] AS[Дата увольнения] FROM Worker";
```

Comment: Вам самой кофмортно ваш код читать в этом вопросе? Оформите код кодом, это не сложно

Comment: `Worker.Firstname AS Имя"+ "Worker.Fathername AS Отчество` - что тут делают кавычки, где пробел между словами, где запятая?

Answer (score 4):

При вот таком склеивании:

```
 "SELECT Worker.ID_Worker AS ID, Worker.Lastname AS Фамилия, Worker.Firstname AS Имя"

+ "Worker.Fathername AS Отчество, Worker.Birthdate AS[Дата рождения], Worker.Address AS Адрес"
```

В результирующей строке между Имя и Worker не будет пробела:

```
...Worker.Firstname AS ИмяWorker.Fathername AS Отчество...
```

Добавьте пробелы в конце каждой строки. Или используйте многострочный литерал, через `@`:

```
string Query_Workers = @"SELECT Worker.ID_Worker AS ID, Worker.Lastname AS Фамилия, Worker.Firstname AS Имя
Worker.Fathername AS Отчество, Worker.Birthdate AS[Дата рождения], Worker.Address AS Адрес
Worker.Tel AS Телефон, Worker.PassData AS[Паспортные данные], Worker.[Date_Employment] AS[Дата приема]
Worker.[Date_Dismissa] AS[Дата увольнения] FROM Worker";
```

Comment: Проблема решена,  все спасибо

Comment: @Вероника не забудьте поставить галочку ответу